Why I need to use passport JS
For example I have RolesGuard:
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, ForbiddenException, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Roles } from './roles.decorator';
import { UserPayload } from 'src/auth/auth.service';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { JwtPayload } from 'src/auth/interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

interface CustomRequest extends Request {
  user?: UserPayload
}

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private reflector: Reflector,
  ) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get(Roles, context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) return true;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<CustomRequest>();
    const [bearer, token] = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')
    
    if (bearer !== 'Bearer' || !token) throw new UnauthorizedException({ message: 'User hasn\'t been authorized' })
    console.log(this.jwtService.decode<JwtPayload>(token))
    const user = this.jwtService.verify<UserPayload>(token)
    request.user = user
    return user.roles.some(role => roles.includes(role.value))
  }
}

why I need to use passport js and how can I create same as strategy  (with getting: this.jwtService.decode<JwtPayload>(token))
What can I do to learn and love the passport js (such questions like how to handle all reject functions or changing input params etc)
P.S. Please say, SHOULD I use Passport JS in production code?
